# CommandFailedException "some FETCH responses could not be transmitted due to errors"

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap

I'm using Javamail 1.5.6 to listen for incoming IMAP messages from a specific mail account.
Some messages, coming always from the same sender, show errors when I try to read their size, please see the following log:

```
"11:48:28.876 E [JavaMail-EventQueue] it.cbt.mail.impl.IMAPFolderSynchronizer:65 - Error notifying message addition
"javax.mail.MessagingException: A588 NO some FETCH responses could not be transmitted due to errors
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.loadEnvelope(IMAPMessage.java:1450)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getSize(IMAPMessage.java:491)
        at it.cbt.mail.impl.IMAPFolderSynchronizer.messagesAdded(IMAPFolderSynchronizer.java:54)
        at javax.mail.event.MessageCountEvent.dispatch(MessageCountEvent.java:153)
        at javax.mail.EventQueue.run(EventQueue.java:168)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: A588 NO some FETCH responses could not be transmitted due to errors
        at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:396)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.loadEnvelope(IMAPMessage.java:1445)
        ... 5 common frames omitted
11:48:28.876 D [JavaMail-EventQueue] my.package.IncomingMailServiceImpl:182 - Notice "cannot map message section for parsing"
```

I thought it was a mail server error, nevertheless if I log-in into mail web-client, I can correctly see those messages which fail when get with Javamail, so I'm confused about the real issue's cause.
Have you ever got this problem?

Thanks in advance, bye

Comment: The web-client is probably not using IMAP.  What is the server?

Comment: Ok I understand, the server should be "Openwave Messaging", do you know it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost certainly a bug in the mail server.  The JavaMail FAQ tells you how to [work around IMAP server bugs](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#imapserverbug).

Comment: Thanks @Bill Shannon. Given that my problem arises on getSize() I suppose I should catch that CommandFailedException and follow second hint in your FAQ, am I right?
"In some cases, the server may be so badly broken that loading the envelope data is not possible, which can cause the above workaround to fail because internally it first fetches the message flags and message size from the server." ?

Comment: The customer service of mail provider has confirmed they had some problems in their IMAP server.
Our StoreListener impl,  showed notices "server shutting down" in those days where CommandFailedException appeared. Thanks Bill